Italian meta-narrative film, 70s? Shot fired in cinema, from the screen, killing audience member
I'm looking for this Italian film, probably from the '70s. I saw this in my youth but can't remember the title. It's a bit "meta"—the film is about a film in a cinema—a spaghetti western.
During one tense moment in the film-within-the-film, a member of the audience is shot dead, and it coincides with a shot being fired on the screen. The audience is kept from leaving by the police, and a reconstruction is staged, with a volunteer taking the victim's chair. During the exact same moment, the same thing happens again.
The film plays with the concept of reality versus fiction, blurring the lines between what happens on screen and in real life, creating a tense and suspenseful atmosphere.

It might help to put an actual likely year you saw this rather than 'in my youth' .... for example if you saw this in 1990 it puts an upper bound on the likely year it was released.

Already asked on SF&F  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/191674/30512

This is Closed Circuit (AKA Circuito Chiuso) (1978).

After a man is shot dead in his seat during a matinee showing of a
Spaghetti Western, the police prevent everyone inside the cinema from
leaving in an effort to nab the culprit.





Yes! Been trying to find this for ages!
